Is there any sequence ${f_n}$ that converges to 0 in measure but $g_n=\frac{f_1 + \cdots f_n}{n}$ does not
Consider [0, 1] with the Lebesgue measure.
Is there any sequence ${f_n}$ of nonnegative integrable functions defined on [0, 1] such that $f_n$ converges to 0 in measure, but the sequence ${g_n}$ defined by $g_n =\frac{f_1 + \cdots + f_n}{n}$ does not converge to 0 in measure?

Welcome to Math.SE! Please provide context to your question; in particular, why do you believe a counterexample may exist? Are you aware of the corresponding result for sequences in $\mathbb R$?
